# Create and download an text file in a client-server system

Tags: javascript, asp.net, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

in ms dynamics crm I will create over an own ribbon button an text file with some contact attributes. This file I would like to save or download to the client machine, so the user can work with it.

How can i do this? I'm going crazy while testing a lot of different ways.

- create with javascript an string and try to downlaod it with data uri. dosen't work

  `var content = "test";`

  `window.open("data:text/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(content));`
- try with silverlight (localy I could create a file) but remote dosen't work
- next try was to fill/create with javascript an *.aspx file on the server and create a text file. But I don't know if this is working or what can i do otherwise?

Please give me some hints to solve this problem.

Comment: It might be an idea to send an e-mail containing the text to be worked with. Otherwise, perhaps adding a web resource and working with contents of an IFRAME would be of use. How large is the text? What kind of text is it (plain, CSV, XML)? How is the user supposed to work with it (reading, editing, uploading back to CRM)?

Comment: a vcf file for outlook import or send colleges etc

Comment: Might be that I'm tired but I don't quite see what the actual problem is. What's not working?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific with the question. What in particular doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it.

In crm i integrated javascript code to open an aspx site.

```
function CreateVCF() 
{
   var entityName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();
   var guid = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
   window.open("http://xxxxx/vcfexport.aspx?guid="+guid+ "&name="+entityName );
}
```

and there i create a vcard and give it back to download

```
public partial class vcfexport : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        //Authenticate using credentials of iis       
        ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();

        Uri OrganizationUri = new Uri("http://server/org/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");
        Uri HomeRealmUri = null;

        OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, HomeRealmUri, Credentials, null);

        IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)serviceProxy;

        String guidString = Request.QueryString["guid"];
        String entityName = Request.QueryString["name"];

        if (guidString != null && entityName != null && guidString != "" && entityName != "") {

            ColumnSet columnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
            Guid guid = new Guid(guidString);

            // retrieve the contact dataset
            Entity contactEntity = service.Retrieve(entityName, guid, columnSet);

            // create new vcard
            VCard vcard = new VCard();
            vcard.FirstName = contactEntity.GetAttributeValue<String>("firstname");
            vcard.LastName = contactEntity.GetAttributeValue<String>("lastname");
            //......

            String fileName = vcard.LastName + " " + vcard.FirstName + ".vcf";

            Response.ContentType = "text/x-vcard";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            // give download window
            Response.Write(vcard.ToString());
            Response.End();


        } else {
            lblError.Text = "Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Entityname oder guid sind falsch";
        }
    }
```